# C sockets (Linux) won't connect

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

recently I've been trying to do a lot with C sockets as it is a language I need for future use. However I've encountered this problem I can't manage to solve. I made both client and server - unfortunately the two binaries refuse to connect in between each other. What I mean is that I do not get any error whatsoever when I run the server binary and client binary in a same machine, but no connection either. Any ideas? Here is the code!

(Ubuntu, both C codes compiled with gcc, server and client code ran within the same machine in 2 different terminals.)

Server.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h> 
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_aton(), inet_ntoa() etc
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>

    #define PORT 8000
    #define ERROR perror("Something went wrong! => ");
    #define BUFFERSIZE 256
    int main()
    {
        int sockfd, client_socketfd; 
        int bytes_sent; 
        socklen_t sin_size;
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        struct sockaddr_in connectedClient_addr;
        char message[BUFFERSIZE] = "Welcome to the server!";

        if((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM ,0)) == -1) {
            ERROR;
            exit(-1);
        }

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port   = htons(PORT);
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Subject to change


        if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))) == -1) {
            ERROR;
            exit(-2);
        }


        if((listen(sockfd, 5)) == -1) {
            ERROR;
            exit(-3);
        }   

        int addrlen = sizeof(connectedClient_addr);
        if((client_socketfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&connectedClient_addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) == -1){
            ERROR;
            exit(-4);
        }   

        printf("Got a connection from: %s at port: %d" , inet_ntoa(connectedClient_addr.sin_addr), PORT);

        if((send(sockfd, &message, BUFFERSIZE, 0)) == -1) {
             ERROR;
             exit(-5);
        }

         close(sockfd);
         close(client_socketfd);

        return 0;
    }
```

--

Client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


#define PORT 8000
#define ERROR perror("Something went wrong! =>");
#define BUFFERSIZE 256
int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    char message[BUFFERSIZE] = "Successfully connected!";
    int bytes_received, bytes_sent;
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];


    if((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        ERROR;
        exit(-1);
    }


    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_addr.sin_port   = htons(PORT);
    client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    if((connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr))) == -1) {
        ERROR;
        exit(-2);
    }

    if((bytes_received = recv(sockfd, &buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0)) == -1) {
        ERROR;
        exit(-3);
    }

    printf("Received %d bytes:\n" , bytes_received);
    printf("%s", buffer);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the `connect` call you have to specify a *specific address*.

Comment: On this line, in the client code : `client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`, you tried to connect the client to any addresses. You need to specify the IP address you want to connect

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun Thank you, will try now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do you mean by "specific address"? Can you provide an example of the connect function?

Comment: A specific IP address. It's not possible to connect to "any" address.

Comment: @RamonSS Specific address means one of the 4 billions IP (well, IPv4) addresses

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun Tried, unfortunately doesn't work. I changed the client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1") to no avail! Any other ideas?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changed to client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");, doesn't work.

Comment: @RyanB. Thank you for joining the conversation. Check the latest reply I made for "Someprogrammerdude".

Comment: What error do you get? And how do you know it's from the connect call? And the server program *is* running on the local host?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have it running in the same machine both server and client. So I do assume localhost, yes. The thing is I do not get any error.

Comment: @RamonSS: `client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");` works just fine when the server is bound to `INADDR_ANY`.  Something else is going wrong.  You say it doesn't work, but then you say you do not get any error. That is a contradiction. `connect()` either succeeds or fails, which is it? Does `connect()` return 0 or -1? If the latter, what does `errno` report?  You should add a log message after `connect()` so you know the client did connect. Also, be sure to zero out `server_addr` and `client_addr` before you populate them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll be back with you in a minute. Going to try out all the stuff you just mentioned.

Comment: Now it's time to read something I should have told you much earlier: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. Read that article, and learn how to use a debugger.  Then step through both client and server with a debugger. That way you will *see* what *really* happens.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I zeroed both structures using bzero(&corresponding_struct, sizeof(corresponding_struct)); and also checked the return of *connect()* which returns 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I stepped through the program with GDB but I do not see any anomalies. I've spent countless hours on this problem. Even googled and searched stack overflow. Wouldn't ask if necessary. So it's either a very tiny problem / some stupid typo I can not see which screws up the whole program or something bigger...

Comment: @RamonSS: the client is successfully connected to the server (you were just not logging that on the client side), but there is a bug in the server, where it is calling `send(sockfd, ...)` when it should be calling `send(client_socketfd, ...)` instead. You are sending the greeting message to the wrong socket descriptor, so there is nothing for the client to read, and `recv()` ends up blocked until the server closes the connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it does return 0 which is a return code for successful connection. However if you see the code the client is supposed to get a message from the server. Server sends "Welcome to the server" and client is supposed to accept that message, and store it in array called buffer. However when I do print that array I just get random gibberish (because the buffer is empty). So like the recv function failed eventhough it returns 0...

Comment: @RamonSS: "*the client is supposed to get a message from the server*" - read my last comment again more carefully. You are sending the message to the WRONG SOCKET, so `recv()` cannot read it! "*the recv function ... returns 0*" - if you [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html), `recv()` returns 0 when the connection is closed gracefully. Which is what happens when the server calls `close()` after `send()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau YES! It works man. I am sorry for the inconvenience but I was writing my replu when you sent these comments. Therefore I didn't see them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I forgot to add a big thank you at the end of the last comment. It does work... Thank you so much! Silly mistake... Add it as an answer so I can set it as the best reply with the green tick? Dunno, this is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**
The issue was that I provided server socket inside `send()` function in *server.c* instead of the client socket. Therefore the code was working without any errors but the behavior was incorrect. Credit goes to [RemyLebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358069/c-sockets-linux-wont-connect#comment77679469_45358069) who pointed this out and saved me countless hours of more struggling.

Comment: The code could not possibly have been 'working without any errors'. You must have failed to check errors on the `send()` function. Clearly either this wasn't the real code or you didn't report all the symptoms.

Comment: @EJP I didn't get a compiler warning nor problem. I just forgot to specify the correct socket. The program was working correctly, how I told it to. Not how I wanted to though. If you think I should modify the final answer submit an edit request and I'll gladly accept it.